# How does one omit the closing slash on <input> elements using WTForms?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I've been noticing that WTForms (and Flask-WTF) output `<input>` elements with a closing slash like so:

`<input name="text" type="text" value="" />`

My documents are HTML5 and therefore need no XHTML-type closure. How would I make WTForms output the input tag as such?

`<input name="text" type="text" value="">`

I've been tearing through the docs and the source code an am finding no clues. I could create a series of custom widgets, of course, but that seems a bit excessive for something so simple. Is there an easier way?

Or is this perhaps a Jinja2 configuration issue that I'm missing?

Comment: Why would you go out of your way to not be backwards compatible?

Comment: I find the closing tags excessive and messy. Older browsers will render non-closed input elements just fine, so I see no compatibility problem here. I'm really fastidious about my markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any revision past [this one](https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/changeset/75dd133de69c) (or simply [download tip](https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/get/tip.tar.gz)) - WTForms is moving to the HTML5 way of generating form elements and adding some new widgets too (I believe). See [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/wtforms/browse_thread/thread/7b4b9a258780542b) and [this one](http://groups.google.com/group/wtforms/browse_thread/thread/99ecee1bdd0da594) for a bit more information.

<sub>* There is also [an extension for WTForms](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/wtforms-xhtml) that adds the XHTML back in, if you decide you need it.</sub>

Comment: Thanks so much! Looks like I'll have to download the tip until 0.6.4 is released.